# Pythonic API design

Tags: python

My objective is to design a Python API that allows clients to do the following:

```
md = MentalDisorders()
print(md.disorders['eating'])
```

to get a list of eating-related disorders.

Here is my stab at it, consider that FAKE_DATABASE will be a real database and I am just focussing this question on the "feel"/"usability" of the interface, especially in a Python context, to which I am alien:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

FAKE_DATABASE = {
  'anxiety': ['phobia', 'panic'],
  'personality': ['borderline', 'histrionic'],
  'eating': ['bulimia', 'anorexia'],
}

class MentalDisorders(object):
  # ... some methods and fields that make it worthwhile having a container class ...
  class DisorderCollection(object):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
      if key in FAKE_DATABASE:
        return FAKE_DATABASE[key]
      else:
        raise KeyError('Key not found: {}.'.format(key))
  def __init__(self):
    self.disorders = self.DisorderCollection()

def main():
  md = MentalDisorders()
  print(md.disorders['anxiety'])
  print(md.disorders['personality'])
  print(md.disorders['eating'])
  try:
    print(md.disorders['conduct'])
  except KeyError as exception:
    print(exception)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

1. Is having a `DisorderCollection` advisable at all?
2. Should `DisorderCollection` be defined within `MentalDisorders` or outside of it?
3. Is instantiating `self.disorders` via `self.DisorderCollection` correct?
4. Should instantiation of a `DisorderCollection` to be used as a field happen from
   within the `__init__` method of `MentalDisorders`?
5. Should perhaps no field instance of `DisorderCollection` exist at all and the above
   be implemented as a simple "forwarding call" from `__getattribute__` to a key
   look-up in the database? What would a simple `md.disorders` (with no key specified)
   return in that case?

Comment: That seems like a really java way of doing it.

Comment: Because I am useless in Python, I come from Java, and I would LOVE to learn how NOT to be so pathetically Java-like! Teach me, please?

Comment: What is `MentalDisorders` if not a `DisorderCollection`. Seems like you want an "is a" relationship, not a "has a". Consider: `m_disorders = MentalDisorders()`, `m_disorders.disorders['...']`. Why am I repeating myself?

Comment: MentalDisorders has other attributes on it. I am focussing on the implementation of "disorders", for which I don't want people to iterate over, only key-based access should be allowed. (Remember, it's a DB behind the scenes..)

Comment: Can you think of a good reason those attributes couldn't be applied directly to `DisorderCollection`? At any rate, that should be a base class, not a member.

Comment: What is a Pythonic way of doing the above?

Comment: Can you give some examples of _"some methods and fields that make it worthwhile having a container class"_, because I don't think any such methods can exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I might write it:

```
class DisorderCollection(object):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in FAKE_DATABASE:
            return FAKE_DATABASE[key]
        else:
            raise KeyError('Key not found: {}.'.format(key))

class MentalDisorders(DisorderCollection):
    # ... some methods and fields that make it worthwhile having a container class ...

class PhysicalDisorders(DisorderCollection):
    # Unless you plan to have multiple types of disorder collections with different methods, I struggle to see a point in the extra layer of classes.

def main():
    md = MentalDisorders()
    print(md['anxiety'])
    print(md['personality'])
    print(md['eating'])
    try:
        print(md['conduct'])
    except KeyError as exception:
        print(exception)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Might even consider making DisorderCollection a subclass of collections.MutableSequence. http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.MutableSequence

Comment: @JosefAssad: At a glance, `collections.MappingView`, looks more appropriate